# Why are there two settings apps, Settings and Settings Storage

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.2-jelly-bean

On my Galaxy Nexus running 4.2.1, I see two Settings apps in Settings > Apps. One is name Settings (28KB) and the other is Settings Storage (520KB). Both have the version 4.2.1-533553. Is the storage one for handling the Settings > Storage screen? If so why is there a separate app for that? If not, what is it for?

Answer (score 2):

Settings Storage, technically speaking, is actually an internal app that manages the *content provider* framework for Settings itself. It also registers itself upon Android boot-up.

The Settings storage backing data store handler, really, uses an [Sqlite database](http://sqlite.org/), which is in the public domain and free to use.

This database is required to hold the settings for updating and retrieval via the Setting's internal *content provider*, which is integrated through-out the ROM in itself, so everything that is seen through Menu > Settings, "talk" to the content provider" and that in itself, handles the backing store.

Also, that Settings own *content provider* is actually global through-out the ROM, irrespective of Android version, so that the system apps and user apps can use that to check on it by querying it and act accordingly.

Hence the *"seeing of two Settings apps"*....

Comment: Most apps I've seen and a few that I've made communicate directly with the SQLite database. Do you have any idea what the benefit of pulling the database into a separate app is?

Comment: Settings is part of the ROM in itself (and not a separate app strictly speaking), when tapping on Menu > Settings, everything in that is stored in the backing database.. specifically, Settings have their own content provider. Some apps need a backing store and some do not craft their own content provider hence directly communicate with Sqlite, depends. But sticking to the context of your question...